# Notepad++: Can I use regex to find some values and remove only one character instead of the whole pattern?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to use regex in notepad to find this pattern: `"[0-9]+[\.][0-9]+[,][0-9]+"` e.g. 1.010,80260
However from these kind of numbers I just want to remove the '.' , so the new value should be 1010,80260 .
So far I can only replace the whole pattern. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `\K` meta escape since PCRE doesn't support variable width lookbehinds:

**regex:**

```regex
[0-9]+\K[\.](?=[0-9]+[,][0-9]+)
```

- `[0-9]+` - capture digits
- `\K` - forget what we've captured
- `[\.]` - capture a period; just `\.` can be used, no need for the char class brackets
- `(?=[0-9]+[,][0-9]+)` - ahead of me should be digits followed by a comma and digits

**replace:**

Nothing

[image]

---

`\K` is bugged in Notepad++ so you could use this regex instead since you only care that at least one digit is behind the period:

```regex
(?<=\d)\.(?=[0-9]+[,][0-9]+)
```

Comment: I had a look at this `\K` (because I am pretty unexperienced in this regexp stuff), and noticed that 'Replace' did not do a thing, but `Replace All` did do the replacements. Maybe that's a bug in Notepad++? I am using version 7.9.5

Comment: @Luuk I'm using v7.9.1. When using the "Replace" button you should take notice that it first highlights the match and then you need to click "Replace" again to perform the operation. This feature let's you verify what you've targeted before committing to the operation. "Replace All" is kind of the YOLO; but easily undo-able with Ctrl+z

Comment: Yeas, I know, I created an animated gif, see: https://gifyu.com/image/BxdQ

Comment: Also added the animated gif to my answer (just as a reference) 

Comment: @Luuk Fun! It fails for me too unless you only have one line of data like my screenshot.

Comment: If you change the regex to `(?<=\d)\.(?=[0-9]+[,][0-9]+)` then it does work. I wonder if `\K` is bugged.

Comment: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8434

Comment: There was an older bug that was closed as a duplicate.  Looks like that bug [has been around a while](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4035#issuecomment-578362713).

Comment: @Gary Thanks, I figured there was a bug report somewhere!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the issues list of notepad++

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Great, thanks for the answer. Works as a charm!

Comment: @Foivos You ought to mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change the regular expression to: `([0-9]+)[\.]([0-9]+[,][0-9]+)`

The `()` pieces are groups which you can refer to in the replace with `\1` for the first group, and `\2` for the second group.

The docs also explain this here: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#substitution-grouping  (even better, and in more detail, than my usage in this answer...)

EDIT: I just wanted to share the animated gif showing that 'Replace' in Notepad++ 7.9.5. does not seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [\K](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), which basically says throw away whatever was matched up until that point, then add a lookahead.  Like so

```
[0-9]+\K\.(?=[0-9]+[,][0-9]+)
```